# Displaying content of the Link Layer Header

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, udp, debian

Are there any debian Linux programs whose commands I can call in a C program, that express a packet's metadata (e.g. protocol, packet length, source and destination ports)? I would use readFrom and sockaddr* structure but I want to be able to receive TCP traffic as well.

Is there any way of using tcpdump to create the string containing this information?

Also, is there anything conceptually wrong in the expression or content of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various alternatives you can use:
1-PCAP as mentioned by Jewel Thief. Example code:

```
int datalink;
char *device;
pcap_t *pd;
int snaplen = MAX_MSG_LEN;
#define CMD "tcp and dst port %d"

void open_pcap()
{
    uint32_t localnet;
    uint32_t netmask;
    char cmd[300];
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    struct bpf_program fcode;

    device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if (device == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR-1: open_pcap:%s\n", errbuf);
        exit(3);
    }

    printf("DEVICE: %s\n", device);

    pd = pcap_open_live(device, snaplen, 0, 500, errbuf);

    if (pd == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR-2-%s\n", errbuf);
        exit(4);
    }

    if (pcap_lookupnet(device, &localnet, &netmask, errbuf) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR-3-%s\n", errbuf);
        exit(5);
    }

    snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), CMD, 80);

    if (pcap_compile(pd, &fcode, cmd, 0, netmask) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR-4-%s\n", pcap_geterr(pd));
        exit(6);
    }

    if (pcap_setfilter(pd, &fcode) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR-5-%s\n", pcap_geterr(pd));
        exit(7);
    }

    datalink = pcap_datalink(pd);

    if (datalink < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR-6-%s\n", pcap_geterr(pd));
        exit(8);
    }

    printf("DATALINK: %d\n", datalink);
}

int getNext(char *msg)
{
    struct pcap_pkthdr hdr;
    char *ptr = NULL;

    while(ptr == NULL)
    {
        ptr = (char *)pcap_next(pd, &hdr);
    }

    printf("LEN: %d - CAPLEN: %d\n", hdr.len, hdr.caplen);
    memcpy(msg, ptr, hdr.caplen);

    return hdr.caplen;
}
```

2-You can use packet sockets

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h> /* the L2 protocols */

packet_socket = socket(AF_PACKET, int socket_type, int protocol);
```

3-You can call command tcpdump with a shell if you don't want to code and this is enough for your needs (look at man for parameters)

Comment: What libraries do I have to include to use pcap?

Additionally, I've tried to use tcpdump in my program with the parameter -e with mixed results. How do I only print the packets coming from a particular client? How do I convert the print output of the command to a string I can use in the code?

Comment: All this you can google. In gcc use libpcap (option -lpcap). For the other questions you can find lots of good responses in stackoverflow or other sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use packet capturing library like PCAP in your C program. You can capture whole packet and analyse its contents. You can even apply packet filtering.

As far as reading is concerned, you can read data from socket just like any other device or file with read system call by giving socket's file descriptor.